# Getting empty folder of adminer after install

Tags: software-installation, 17.04

My `/etc/adminer/` folder is empty after installing `adminer` using command:

```
sudo apt-get install adminer
```

And it is not accessible in URL `localhost/adminer`.

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 and adminer 4.2.5

Comment: Have you followed some guide or did you just write "sudo apt install adminer". Some more information is always viable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files under `/usr/share/adminer/` are still present. It looks like the packager deleted the adminer.conf which was supposed to be in /etc/adminer according to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/adminer/+bug/1609326